# Gatling increase users using a multiple

Tags: java, scala, testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am new to gatling and looking for a wayt to increase the number of numers following a linear function such as 5n for a fixed duration.

I saw the following method

constantUsersPerSec but it is a constatn function. It basically means for example 5 users every seconds.

I am also looking for a way to do it until the response time is greater than desired response time.

Below is my code:

```
setUp(
    scenario(10).inject(
      atOnceUsers(1)
    ).protocols(httpProtocol),

    scenarioService(5000).inject(
      nothingFor((10 + 10) seconds),
      constantUsersPerSec(5) during (4 minutes)
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
  )
    .maxDuration(dureeDuTestEnMinutes minutes)
    .assertions(
      global.responseTime.max.lt(tempsReponseLimiteAvantEchecEnMillisecondes)
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Comment: Did you look at `rampUsersPerSec`?

Comment: I does not fit my need. I uses to rates. I get your idea.  I don't really see how we can get to let's say rate2: 5n from a rate1: 1n.